# Joomla : how adding an explanation image into manifest file

Tags: joomla, joomla-module

In my how modules I write, I'd like to add an image in order to illustrate one or more user action.
How can I include an image into my XML manifest files of my modules ou plugins ?
I'd like to have this result

I try to had a description (in HTML for example) into a Joomla Plugin or Module Manifest file

https://imgur.com/F2y08I3

On this imgur image, I'd like to reproduce yhe second bottom part where I have paste in Image of REGEX help

Thanks